# How to add options menu (three dot menu buttom ) in iOS(swift 3) custom tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios7

I am new to iOS programming. I am working on an app that will ask user to choose options shown in the image. I want to build it programmatically. Can someone help me with that?

Each row has three dot menu option:

[image: In this you can see each row has three dot menu option]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question is very broad. Besides that, as far as I remember, the three dots are an android thing and you should not port features between the systems to not confuse users.

Comment: I know its an android thing, so is there any other way that we can do this kind of things in ios or any alternate way to show options. @Capricorn

Comment: Instead of this popover, you can use alert with sheet style. It will be much easier to implement and will follow iOS style.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to create a custom `UITableViewCell`, and place a button on the right side of the cell with its image as the three-dot menu that you referenced. You can accomplish this by subclassing `UITableViewCell`. There are numerous examples of this online.